# Make connection from Postgresql to QGIS?

Tags: postgresql, qgis-2

I'm still new in QGIS.

I want to add data from one layer to another layer in QGIS.

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't, you connect QGIS to Postgresql. The QGIS manual is very complete, I suggest you start there. This site is not for basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Apperantly, from your question I think you need to have some basic concept on database management(esp spatial database) and GIS softwares(QGIS) too.Both QGIS and PostgreSQL have comprehensive documentation you really need to consult with.
To add @ John Barça, You can not connect postgresql to qgis rather reverse is done to solve the problem. If you need to deal with (spatial data and you must  use in qgis) you need postgis plugin in postgresql. I would use eVis if PostGIS (PostgreSQL) is configured.

[image: postgis]